# is there some tool that could convert xml with schema constriction into binary

Tags: xml, xsd, xerces

Given a schema xsd and xml file like below, is there any tools that could convert the xml data into binary representation of "0x000000ff 0x61626364"?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">

  <xs:element name="testElem" type="testType"/>

  <xs:complexType name="testType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="myID" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:unsignedInt"/>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="myName" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string"/>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<testElem>
  <myID>255</myID>
  <myName>abcd</myName>
</testElem>
```

Comment: "convert to binary". What exactly do you want to achieve? What language are you using (programming language as opposed to markup language). Please give a precise example of what you are trying to do: "When the XML file says X, I want my variable A to contain B and be printed as 011011101010011 when I use a print command like *****"

Answer (score 2):

In Saxon we've implemented but not yet released the EXPath binary module described here:

http://expath.org/spec/binary

which could handle this. You could then write a schema-aware XSLT stylesheet with rules like

```
<xsl:template match="element(*, xs:unsignedBinary)">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of select="xs:hexBinary(bin:pack-integer(.))"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="element(*, xs:string)">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of select="xs:hexBinary(bin:encode-string(., 'us-ascii'))"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```